# Open a spreadsheet and add a menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet I want to open from a web app then add a menu to that spreadsheet:

```
    function openSheet(){
      var ssCentral = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
      ssCentral.getUi()
       .createMenu('ZettaReport')
       .addItem ('Activate Reporting for a New Member','activateNewMember')
       .addToUi();
    }
```

this function is called by google.run.script.openSheet() once I click a button

```
   <script>
     document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",launchReport)
function launchReport() {
  window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  google.script.run.openSheet();  
}
```

I see the function is called by the menu is not added....

Comment: Only a user can open a Spreadsheet that way.

Comment: To manipulate the UI, a script instance must be bound to the associated document and the browser window with that open document must be the one initiating the UI call. Use the "open" trigger

Comment: thanks @tehhowch  - you are right!